# Get x max for svg viewbox

Tags: javascript, svg, viewbox

I have an `svg` element, where height and width both equal 100%, with a defined `viewbox` attribute. The `svg` contains a range of `polygon` objects. On clicking a polygon, I want it to expand to fill the entire `svg` (read: the entire screen).

I can access the `svg` element dimensions and resize the `polygon` accordingly, but due to the `viewbox` attribute, plotting the width comes up short.

Is there any way to calculate the x dimension within the viewbox which corresponds to the far right edge?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum X value you want will be the maximum X of the viewBox, which you can calculat by adding the viewBox `minX` + the viewBox `width`.

Comment: I think there's more to it than that (probably a coefficient involved) - minX + viewbox width gets to the bounding edge of the g element, not the actual svg. Think it's to do with the aspect ratio and how that determines the offset of the svg. Have changed my approach and found something more workable. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, you didn't make it clear that you were dealing with preserveAspectRatio etc.  That is hard because the SVG doesn't really know the shape of the container it is in - and shouldn't really care.  The viewBox is meant to describe the bounds of the document - or at least the bounds you are interested in.  If you are drawing outside that then you should really be updating the viewBox to match.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realise it preserveAspectRatio was involved until after I'd posted - which lead to finding a better way to achieve what I needed, sans measuring